# Highcharts not able to access z value

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

```
$(function () {
    $('#containerGraph').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        exporting: { enabled: false },
        credits: { enabled: false },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
             title: {
                text: 'Date'

            },

            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '10px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                colorByPoint: true
            }
        },   

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Time (minutes)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {

            //pointFormat: '<b>{point.y:.1f} minutes</b>{point.x:}'
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.y +'</b>'+
                    'minutes<br>'+ this.point.z + 'hi' ;
        },
        //shared: true
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Time',
            data: [
                ['<?php print $buildDate[0]?>', <?php print $lastFifteenDurationArray[0]?>, <?php echo $svnHistory[0]?>],
                ['<?php print $buildDate[1]?>', <?php print $lastFifteenDurationArray[1]?>, <?php print $svnHistory[1]?>],
                ['<?php print $buildDate[2]?>', <?php print $lastFifteenDurationArray[2]?>, <?php print $svnHistory[2]?>],
                ['<?php print $buildDate[3]?>', <?php print $lastFifteenDurationArray[3]?>, <?php print $svnHistory[3]?>],
                ['<?php print $buildDate[4]?>', <?php print $lastFifteenDurationArray[4]?>, <?php print $svnHistory[4]?>],
                ['<?php print $buildDate[5]?>', <?php print $lastFifteenDurationArray[5]?>, <?php print $svnHistory[5]?>]




            ],


            lang: {noData: "No Data Available"},
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

The value of z-axiz in the tooltip shows Undefined in the chart.

I also tried this.point.config[2], but that doesn't work either.
When I debugged the code, the z-value in the data field is correctly resolved.

Is it because I have to specify type of data or something?
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show what is there in data???

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zf7tgvLg/

Answer (score 1):

In case you wan't a third dimension you'll need to define it like this:  `data = [{y: yValue, z: zValue, additional: additionalVal}]`, like this you can access `this.point.z` (and this.point.additional). Anyway, it seems that using the *series X values* as *x-axis category label* does not work while working with an array of objects. In order to make it run, do it like this:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    categories: ['09-01-2015','09-01-2015'], /* your old x-data */
    title: {
        text: 'Date'
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Time',
    /* data is now an array of objects */
    data: [
        {y:25, z:492076},
        {y:26, z:496222}
    ],
}
```

[updated Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/zf7tgvLg/1/)

Comment: How will you do this with multiple series data?